# validar o tamanho da imagem php

Tags: php

Estou a receber uma imagem `$image` que tem o caminho da imagem (Ex: ./files/full/imagem.png). O que quero fazer é buscar o tamanho da mesma, altura e largura, e validar se é maior que uma valor pré-definido (por exemplo 400x300). Ou seja, se a imagem for menor que 400x300 dará erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`getimagesize($imagem)`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getimagesize.php):

```
<?php
$imagem = 'php-imagem.jpg';

// Captura o tamanho da imagem e guarda nas variáveis
list($largura, $altura) = getimagesize($imagem);

// Faz a Validação da imagem
if($largura == 250 && $altura == 100)
{
    echo 'Imagem com tamanho correto.';
}
else
{
    echo "Imagem com tamanho incorreto. (Tamanho da Imagem: $largura x $altura px.)";
}
?>
```

*Fonte: [Validar tamanho da imagem com PHP](http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/validar-tamanho-da-imagem-com-php).*